# Django ORM: Group by and Max

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a model that looks like this:

```
Requests: user, req_time, req_text
```

In the DB, the records can look like this:

```
id, user_id, req_time, req_text
1     1      TIMESTAMP  YES
2     1      TIMESTAMP  NO
3     2      TIMESTAMP  YES
```

etc.

How do I write a Django ORM query that: groups the Requests by user, filters the Requests based on req_text, and also, select the max id of the resulting result set. So for each user, I will return one row which matches the filter condition and also has the greatest id.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
from django.db.models.aggregates import Max

request_values = Requests.objects.filter(req_text='YES') \
                 .values('user') \
                 .annotate(max_id=Max('id'))
```

Then `request_values` will look like this:

```
[
    {'user': 1, 'max_id': 1},
    {'user': 2, 'max_id': 4},
    {'user': 3, 'max_id': 5},
    {'user': 4, 'max_id': 12},
    ...
]
```

Comment: type(request_values) == django.db.models.query.ValuesQuerySet but elements of a ValuesQuerySet are dictionaries and not Django objects anymore. Is there a way to get a QuerySet out of that query?

Comment: @kev it doesn't make sense to ask for model instances from a GROUP BY query as each row of the results does not represent a single row from the table any more

Comment: yeah, that absolutely makes sense

Comment: I thought that to be right, but it doesn't work for me. I have the exact same problem and had exactly the same solution. It seems the problem occurs when I add a second filter for some reason.

Comment: ...And ٌWHICH ANSWER IS BETTER THAN THIS?  **thank you**. It working.

Comment: @dengar81 the catch I had was that default `ordering` added `order_by` clause to my query which messed it up!

Comment: What if i wanted to get the row/instance with that max_id for each user? Is that possible ? The result would be something like `[ {'user': 1, 'max_id/id': 2, 'req_time': TIMESTAMP, 'req_text': NO}, {'user': 2, 'max_id/id': ... }, ... ]`