# Django queryset order by related model with distinct

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following two models:

```py
class Show(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Episode(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    series = models.ForeignKey('Show', related_name='episodes')
```

I want to retrieve all instances of `Show` which have `is_active` set to `True` and which have at least 1 `Episode`. The part I'm having trouble with is that I also want the `Show` instances to be ordered by the related `Episode` `start` field and for the `Show` instances to be unique.

Is this possible with a single query?

What I have tried:

```py
Show.objects.annotate(
    e_count=Count('episodes')
).filter(
    e_count__gt=0,
    is_active=True,
).order_by('episodes__start').distinct()
```

Comment: Try ordering by the `MAX()` of the episode start time. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940255/django-orm-group-by-and-max).

Comment: Thank you! this didn't occur to me. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved this by using `Min`, as suggested by Anonymous.

```py
Show.objects.filter(
    is_active=True,
).annotate(
    e_count=Count('episodes'),
    start=Min('episodes__start'),
).filter(
    e_count__gt=0,
    start__gt=timezone.now(),
).order_by('start')
```