# Django ORM for select max(field1) from table group by (field2);

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

I have the following model:

```
class Transition(models.Models):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  transition_type = models.IntegerField(dbcolumn='transition_typeid')
  instance = models.IntegerField(dbcolumn='instanceid')
  ts = models.DateTimeField()
  class Meta:
    managed=False
    db_table = 'transitions'
```

I'd like to issue the following query using Django's ORM:

```
select max(id) from transitions group by(instanceid);
```

I know I can use a raw query as follows:

```
Transition.objects.raw('select max(id) from transitions group by (instanceid)')
```

However, the downside is that the query seems to be getting executed instantly and
doesn't lend it self to further filtering, for example I'd like to get a query
set to which a further filter on say timestamp can be applied.

Is there way to use a purely ORM way to issue the select statement above without using Django's raw queries?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940255/django-orm-group-by-and-max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work for you

```
Transition.objects.values('instance').annotate(Max('id'))
```

docs : [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/](http://docs%20aggregation)

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly.