# Get latest query for user in django queryset

Tags: django, sqlite

```
class Revision(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(
        db_index=True,
        verbose_name=_("date created"),
        help_text="The date and time this revision was created.",
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        verbose_name=_("user"),
        help_text="The user who created this revision.",
    )

    comment = models.TextField(
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=_("comment"),
        help_text="A text comment on this revision.",
    )
```

I need to get the latest entry for each user. But I can’t build a normal query. I am using sqlite3 database

Comment: maybe use the max function on date_created using annotation and values See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses for similar scenario. Note, you'll get the values, not the actual object.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6944157/4872140

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Revision.objects.values('user').annotate(Max('date_created'))
```