# django orm inner join group by data

Tags: django

```
class Dishes(models.Model):
    """ 菜品"""
    cuisine_list = ((0, '川菜'), (1, '粤菜'), (2, '徽菜'), (3, '湘菜'))

    name = models.CharField('菜名', max_length=100)
    material = models.TextField('材料')
    cuisine = models.IntegerField('菜系', choices=cuisine_list)
    price = models.IntegerField('价格')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

how to select ： Information about the most expensive dish in each cuisine, including dish names and ingredients

```
Dishes.objects.values('cuisine').annotate(max_price=Max("price"))
```

In this way, we can only find the information with the highest price in each cuisine, excluding the names and ingredients of the dishes. It would be fine if we could query for cuisine and max_price from inner join, but what should we write in ORM?

Comment: 如何查询出： 每个菜系中价格最高的菜的信息，包括菜名和材料

```Dishes.objects.values('cuisine').annotate(max_price=Max("price")) ```这样只能找到 每个菜系中价格最高的信息，不包含 菜名和材料. 如果 Dishes 能 inner join 查询出来的 cuisine 和 max_price 就可以了，但是用 orm 该怎么写？？

Comment: Does this help - which database are you using? https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/61934/django-group-by-one-field-only-take-the-latest-max-of-each-group-and-get-back-the-orm-objects

Comment: The database I'm using is mysql @AMG

Comment: Your problem seems to be to get the `group_by` clause into the query, and this should answer it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940255/django-orm-group-by-and-max

Answer (score 1):

If using Postgresql you may be able to use the following :

```
Dishes.objects.all().order_by().order_by(
    'cuisine', # to group by this value
    '-price' # descending by price will put highest first
).distinct('cuisine')
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct for a description. Also see https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/61934/django-group-by-one-field-only-take-the-latest-max-of-each-group-and-get-back-the-orm-objects for a further discussion on similar problem and source for this suggestion.

Decent explanation of `Distinct On` available at: https://www.geekytidbits.com/postgres-distinct-on/